# Casting votes to old posts

Tags: discussion, voting, badges

To be honest, I want to obtain the electorate gold badge. Some people in this site commented to do 40 votes/day in 15 consecutive days. My question is, can I vote to questions being posted long time ago, say for instance, those posted on the years 2010-2014? Are these votes credited to the electorate gold badge? OR do I have to cast my votes to recent questions only. I really don't know what to do. Sorry for this, I am new to this meta exchange.

Comment: I think it's a *misconception* of a lot of people that one shouldn't vote old posts. It's really quite simple: if a post you saw was interesting/useful to you, then vote it up, and *never mind what date and time it was posted*. (P.S., yes, it'll count)

Comment: @ J. M. isn't a mathematician Thanks for the nice comment.

Comment: To clear up another apparent misconception I've seen: it is perfectly fine to vote for more than one answer to a question, and it is also fine to upvote answers that are not the accepted one; just go with what you felt after reading the answer.

Comment: I despise gamification, and people who do something just for the sake of having a badge. Nevertheless, I do appreciate that you asked this here, since it shows that you're uncomfortable with blindly voting all the things that come across your way just to get a badge. So if you've set to get the Electorate badge, be sure to actually read the answers you vote, and decide they are worth of your vote. After a few thousand votes I can tell you that if you end up waiting another day or three because of that, but you only voted high quality content, then you've done well.

Comment: If you actually want to help the site, look for answers with currently 0 votes that you feel are good answers.

Comment: @ Asaf Karagila Great advice. Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no criterion the questions needs to satisfy for your vote to count towards the electorate badge, beyond it being a *question* post.

It can be old or new, it can be highly-vote, lowly voted or not voted at all before. It can be Community Wiki or not. Also note upvotes and downvotes count. It's also not a problem if the questions gets deleted later (and due to this I believe one could even do it in less than 15 days; that's not meant as encouragement to try it).

You see, you can vote whatever you like for the badge. It would be nice though that you still make an effort to cast the votes in a meaningful way. For example, to vote with consideration on old, low-scoring questions in your field of expertise could be a useful service.