# how to know why one's question was downvoted?

Tags: discussion, down-votes

This is a repeated question which pops up.
How is one suppose to know why was a question downvoted so they can improve it? Recently two of my questions were downvoted. Here is the image.

[image]
And the links.
[What is wrong with this solution of find the least value of $ \sec^6 x +\csc^6 x + \sec^6 x\csc^6 x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3168377/what-is-wrong-with-this-solution-of-find-the-least-value-of-sec6-x-csc6-x)
[Find the least value of $ \sec^6 x +\csc^6 x + \sec^6 x\csc^6 x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3166878/find-the-least-value-of-sec6-x-csc6-x-sec6-x-csc6-x)
What can one do about it?
Except for individually asking on meta for every single question.

perhaps relevant(this probably increased the views and drove traffic to those two questions).[What is the {real} meaning of duplicate question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30110/what-is-the-real-meaning-of-duplicate-question?noredirect=1#comment128796_30110)

Comment: Unless someone leaves a comment, you cannot know why it was downvoted.

Comment: @XanderHenderson perhaps one can suggest possible reasons for it? So that I can improve my post.

Comment: "This is a repeated question which pops up." And what didn't you understand about the answers that were given the other times it popped up?

Comment: @GerryMyerson I never 'asked' a question along that lines. Except this of course. They often pop and disappear in my brain.

Comment: I didn't write that *you* had asked the question, only quoted your assertion that the question had popped up. I took this to mean that others had posted this question on meta before – isn't that what you meant? And if others have posted it before, why post it again?

Comment: @GerryMyerson  I did some research, but didn't find a general question about a this issue, only for a perticular question.

Comment: "*perhaps relevant(this probably increased the views and drove traffic to those two questions).*" might be, you just invoked [the meta effect](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/235225/what-is-the-meta-effect)

Comment: Previous "why the downvote?" questions: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29872/new-user-reason-for-downvotes-on-question and https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29855/what-about-this-question-earned-some-quantity-of-downvotes and https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29299/unfair-downvoting-of-question and https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28641/why-is-the-reason-for-the-down-and-close-vote-for-this-question and https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28386/why-was-this-question-downvoted

Comment: Also https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27698/is-there-any-obvious-reason-why-my-very-old-answer-was-downvoted and https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27232/when-someone-gives-you-2-points and https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26709/why-has-this-question-so-many-downvotes and https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26573/is-it-possible-to-see-the-reason-for-down-votes and probably two dozen others. Surely *one* of these is relevant here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an asymmetry here. People always want to know why their questions/answers were downvoted, but give no thought to why they were upvoted. I have received upvotes that were not really deserved, but it didn't cross my mind to ask why the upvotes!

In short: upvotes/downvotes have a random element, and worrying about every one is a fruitless exercise. Put it down to the weather.

Comment: Yes, upvotes can be really random. In fact my highest votes I have on an answer, which I consider pretty bad, and I always wondered why everyone seemed to like it that much... I think it is just an effect, that people tend to upvote questions/answers which already have a lot of votes. And also they tend to downvote these with a lot of downvotes. But when you write an answer, which you think is helpful and you really wanted to help with it, a downvote without any explaination seems just unfair. And in my opinion there should be a reason given for the downvote, which only the auther sees.

Comment: @Cornman someone should post it as a feature request on meta. Should one?

Comment: @swarnim no, because it has been asked many times and [just shot down](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357436/why-isnt-providing-feedback-mandatory-on-downvotes-and-why-are-ideas-suggestin)

Comment: When a question is upvoted it means it is a good question. Nothing to worry about. Nothing to change. Things are working fine. When a post is down voted it means exactly opposite of all above listed points.

Comment: @swarnim: No and no. Upvotes and downvotes can be completely random. Once you realise this, those downvotes will stop bothering you :-)

Comment: @swarnim To exemplify what TonyK said, sometimes people upvote (downvote) to get the "Electorate" gold badge.

Comment: @YuiTo, you have evidence of that?

Comment: @GerryMyerson For example, [this post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25564/casting-votes-to-old-posts)

Comment: OK, @YuiTo, so *one person* did it. One person isn't "people".

Comment: @GerryMyerson I apologized for the overgeneralization. My intention is to convince the OP that sometimes upvotes (downvotes) are mysterious.